# Run time error 91 object variable or with block variable not set

Tags: excel, vba

this simple code get this error.
why?

```
 Sub ScaleAxes()
With ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary)
    .MaximumScale = ActiveSheet.Range("A33").Value
 End With
```

End Sub

Comment: Depending on which line the error is occurring in: if it is the line `With...` then there is a worksheet active, and if it is the line `.MaximumScale...` then the `ActiveChart` is currently the `ActiveSheet` and has no `Range` property. Note that there is no `ActiveWorksheet` property.

Comment: i have only one sheet with only one chart. can be not the active one?

Comment: this occurring on the with line. what does mean "there is a worksheet active"?

Comment: thanks. now im getting "Object doesn't support this property or method"

Comment: is this question about VBA or VBScript? Please use the correct tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### A Chart/ChartObject Investigation

- The (OP's) setup is only one worksheet with an embedded chart (object).
- The following is illustrating various ways to write your code. All the procedures do the same except the last one which is testing what is active. Choose one of them or create another.
- This is just an object-investigation since I know nothing about charts and I didn't want to check the documentation. You should probably investigate on *Charts vs Worksheets vs Sheets* and *Chart vs ChartObject* and *Axes vs Axis*.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestChart()
    Dim ch As Chart: Set ch = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart
    With ch.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary)
        .MaximumScale = ActiveSheet.Range("A33").Value
    End With
End Sub

Sub TestChartObject()
    Dim cho As ChartObject: Set cho = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1")
    With cho.Chart.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary)
        .MaximumScale = ActiveSheet.Range("A33").Value
    End With
End Sub

Sub testAxesActiveSheet()
    With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary)
        .MaximumScale = ActiveSheet.Range("A33").Value
    End With
End Sub

Sub testAxesTripleParent()
    With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary)
        .MaximumScale = .Parent.Parent.Parent.Range("A33").Value
    End With
End Sub

Sub testAxes()
    With ActiveSheet
        Dim axs As Axis
        Set axs = .ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary)
        axs.MaximumScale = .Range("A33").Value
    End With
End Sub

Sub testAxesChart()
    With ActiveSheet
        Dim ch As Chart: Set ch = .ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart
        Debug.Print ch.Name ' Result?: 'Sheet1 Chart 1'
        Dim axs As Axis: Set axs = ch.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary)
        axs.MaximumScale = .Range("A33").Value
    End With
End Sub

Sub testAxesChartObject()
    With ActiveSheet
        Dim cho As ChartObject: Set cho = .ChartObjects("Chart 1")
        Debug.Print cho.Name ' Result: 'Chart 1'
        Dim axs As Axis: Set axs = cho.Chart.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary)
        axs.MaximumScale = .Range("A33").Value
    End With
End Sub

Sub TestActiveChart()
    On Error GoTo SheetError
    Debug.Print "ActiveSheet Name: " & ActiveSheet.Name
    On Error GoTo ChartError
    Debug.Print "ActiveChart Name: " & ActiveChart.Name
ProcExit:
    Exit Sub
SheetError:
    Debug.Print "No active sheet."
    Resume Next
ChartError:
    Debug.Print "No active chart."
    Resume Next
End Sub
```